# spring boot @autowired filed injected with null in the @configuration class but worked with @import

Tags: spring, configuration, null, spring-boot, autowired

According to the reference [using-boot-configuration-classes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-configuration-classes.html), I used `@ComponentScan` on the Application class and use the `@Configuration` on my config class, in my config class, I want to inject beans defined in other config class by using `@Autowired` annotation, but when I run the application, I got null for these fields, I tried to use `import` on the application and remove the `@Configuration` from config class, everything works fine.

Is it a bug of `spring boot` or I am misunderstanding about the usage of `@Configuration` annotation?

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: there isn't a bug in spring boot... works for many people.. probably your classes layout is not right.. please share your layout or just have a look at the examples..

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to autowire other configuration classes into Application class?
Use a fresh method along with @PostConstruct to make it call automatically after Spring creates an instance of Application class.